# how to loop for array json in controller symfony3

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, symfony, loops

hello i send array json from ajax to controller in symfony 3 now i want to loop for this array this my function but in my controller iget this issue

Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::$startDate

```
  $('.btnEnregistrerAnnonce').click(function (){
            alert("hellobtn");


            $.ajax({
            url:'{{ (path('deleteventdate')) }}',
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                arrayDeleted: arrayDeleted
            },
            async: true,
            success: function (data)
            {
                console.log("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
                console.log(data);
                //$('.formAdd').submit();


            }
        });
      });
```

in data arrayDeleted a have my array 
this My controller

```
public function deleteArray(Request $request)
{
    $test = $request->get('arrayDeleted');

    $array = new JsonResponse($test);
    foreach ($array  as $arr)
    {
        echo $arr->startDate ;
    }
```

}

this is result of arrayDeleted in console

```
 {startDate: "2018-10-25", endDate: "2018-10-28", idAd: 3}
```

thanks you for any help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i fixed my issue using `json_encode` instead of `json_decode` thanks for you

Comment: this is what i do  :   $content = $request->getContent();
                               $data = json_encode($content, true);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get your posted data in a wrong way. Also, the `JsonResponse` class is for returning a response, not decoding json data.

```
public function deleteArray(Request $request)
{
    $content = $request->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($content, true); // 2nd parameter to get data as array

    $arrayDeleted = $data['arrayDeleted'];

    dump($arrayDeleted ['startDate']); // do something with $arrayDeleted ['startDate']

    // return a response

}
```

Comment: i try your solution but i get this issue :  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: sorry my mistake, fixed my answer

Comment: i fixe my issue using json_encode instead of json_decode thanks for you

Comment: You should edit your question to better explain what you want to do. json_encode doesn't fit in any case for a problem like this you described